# Same query on different tables - Scala Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I've tried eliminate duplicated code in scala but with no success.

What I have:

```
(table.filter(someFilters).map(columns).result map { res =>
 res foreach { case (data1, data2, data3) =>
 //some logic
}}) >>
(differentTable.filter(sameFilters).map(sameColumns).result map { res =>
 res foreach { case (data1, data2, data3) =>
 //other logic
}})
```

return type is DBIOAction

How is it possible to not duplicate this code and execute logic based on what type of table it is?

*The two tables have no relation between them

Comment: If there is no relation between the tables, what does `sameFilters` do? How does it refer to columns? What is the type of `res` in your example?

Comment: You can do something like `functionThatActsOnThreeStringColumns(table1.map(row => (row.a, row.b, row.c))` as well as `functionThatActsOnThreeStringColumns(table2.map(row => (row.x, row.y, row.z))` (extracting the common columns into a tuple type for the function to work with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do one thing here.

```
 val table1 = TableQuery[Table1]
 val table2 = TableQuery[Table2]
```

Let's say you have table type `T`

```
def  findAll[T](table: T)  = {
   (table.filter(someFilters).map(columns).result map { res =>
   res foreach { case (data1, data2, data3) =>
    //some logic
  }}) 
  }
```

Since your `findAll` takes generic table name and you mentioned you have all the columns identical, then call findAll like below :

```
     findAll[Table1](table1) 
     findAll[Table2](table2)
```

Hope this helps